# Wrong sql execution plan when I use same the query, but in different databse context

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

Can someone please me explain, why I have two different execution plan for the same t-sql query?
When I in the query used full table name with the name of the database and only I changed database context by command "Use". Query, but should execute, on the same database, because the query contains full name conventions.
It doesn't make sense to me!

[Show two different exec-plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy5lyH_OP)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). If you are posting query plans, use [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Perhaps your master database have a scoped configuration of 1 for MAXDOP that  PHARDB_COME_DEV doesn't... See sys.database_scoped_configurations. But without any more information about version, edition and contextual application, we cannot do more...

Answer (score -1):

they are basically the same query plan , except one went parallel.
It might be MAXDOP configuration is different for the databases you are running the query from ,

Comment: The plans are totally different, the tables are in different orders and one uses a different join opperator.

Comment: that join is to merge the result of the parallel  operators .

Answer (score -1):

Query plans are based on statistics which are based on the distribution of your data at a point in time.  If the table definitions are the same and the data in all three tables are exactly the same and the statistics have been updated then you may expect to see similar plans (although this would depend on database settings and any difference in hardware if querying on two different servers).

In your case, I suspect that there is a discrepancy in the statistics in the two databases.

Comment: both queries are query the same database ,